# Setting focus to cell wxGrid

Tags: python, wxpython, wxgrid

How can I set focus to specific cell in wxGrid?
For example, I catch enter pressed event in one cell, and I want to gain focus to cell
which is on the right to that one.
Default behavior is to gain focus to cell below when enter is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wxpython demo shows you how to do this

```
import  wx
import  wx.grid as  gridlib

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class NewEnterHandlingGrid(gridlib.Grid):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.log = log

        self.CreateGrid(20, 6)

        self.SetCellValue(0, 0, "Enter moves to the right")
        self.SetCellValue(0, 5, "Enter wraps to next row")
        self.SetColSize(0, 150)
        self.SetColSize(5, 150)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown)


    def OnKeyDown(self, evt):
        if evt.GetKeyCode() != wx.WXK_RETURN:
            evt.Skip()
            return

        if evt.ControlDown():   # the edit control needs this key
            evt.Skip()
            return

        self.DisableCellEditControl()
        success = self.MoveCursorRight(evt.ShiftDown())

        if not success:
            newRow = self.GetGridCursorRow() + 1

            if newRow < self.GetTable().GetNumberRows():
                self.SetGridCursor(newRow, 0)
                self.MakeCellVisible(newRow, 0)
            else:
                # this would be a good place to add a new row if your app
                # needs to do that
                pass


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Simple Grid Demo", size=(640,480))
        grid = NewEnterHandlingGrid(self, log)



#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = wx.App()
    frame = TestFrame(None, sys.stdout)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```